# Pixi js. How to add child to parents without changing it's local position

Tags: pixi.js

So in pixi I have two Sprite parents and child. After creating parents and child Sprite. I change the scale of parents and add some rotation value. After these when I add child to parents using `parents.addChild()` method. My child position is changing from the original position.

How can add child to parents without changing it's original position.
Notes: some time i can have multiple node of parents and we might add child to the last node.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your transformation before adding child and after adding the apply reverse transformation to bring it back to original position.

Comment: In sprite I have two positions property world pos and local pos. I can only read world pos and can't write it. So how I am going to take world pos data and convert it local pos relative to all the child node.